# Install Stock Rom on dead screen phone

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, root-access, rom-flashing

I am using Iball Andi 4.5 K6 (Android 4.4). Well my phone doesn't have OTG support but has root access. While deleting some bloatware apps I deleted some apps which has made the screen disabled(touch is not working). Hence I decided to flash the ROM. I was able to open the recovery but the screen was not working so I was not able to flash the ROM.But then I left the phone for about an year. 
Now I am not able to go to the recovery since my volume buttons seems to be not working. Hence I tried connecting my phone to laptop and tried to go to recovery or fastboot using adb commands but it didn't worked as my USB Debuging options is turned OFF. Hence,

1. I cannot go to recovery / fastboot manually.
2. I cannot make adb commands work until my USB Debugging is turned ON, and my phone doesn't support OTG so that's not an option.
3. My screen is disabled. Only power on button is working

So is there any way thorugh which I can completely format whole phone and install the Recovery and ROM without using screen.

Comment: Unlikely unless you get your buttons repaired. To install a (custom) recovery you'd either need to use an app like ROMManager (doesn't work as your touch screen is dead), or you need to flash it from fastboot/bootloader – which you cannot reach as neither USB debugging is available (for `adb reboot bootloader`) nor your volume keys are working (for manually boot into bootloader/recovery). Even if your device had a [tag:power-options] menu which lets you boot into recovery/bootloader, you again couldn't use that with a dead touch screen. Service center might have other options.

Answer (score 1):

Spflash tool is supported for your device. Thus you won't need to turn on your phone. You'll first have to install the drivers for your device on PC. Then download the stock ROM for your device. Then remove the battery and flash via spflash tool.

This might help you: http://www.gogorapid.com/flash-stock-rom-iball-andi-4-5-k6/